# Android RIL Modem GPRS

Tags: android, modem, gprs, ril

I am trying integrate a GPRS modem in Android 6.0.1 without success. Modem works well at hardware level and answer correctly AT commands. In Android UI I only see SIM card not present and nothing related to modem works.

In Android log I can see a lot of subId=-2, phoneId=-1, slotId=-1, I think my problem is because of this wrong numbers.

Someone with experience in Android RIL could help me to understand how this numbers are generate and where?

I think my reference-ril.c is OK, and I can't understand why this Id are not generate correctly.

Comment: Can you copy paste the radio log. Generate the log using the following command: `adb logcat -b radio > test_log.txt`. The issue does not seem to be these paramters as I have a working RIL with these parameters not passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all the case PhoneId equals slotId, it means which SIM card slot the current subscription is on.
SubId maintain a record for SIM cards that have been inserted. eg, You insert a card with Iccid 46332223***3232 and the telephony record it as a subId=1, for another card with Iccid 46332223***9900, telephony record it as SubId=2.....Next when you insert 46332223***3232 again, telephony will know it's an acquaintance card, and SubId will again set as subId=1. So it's for other cards.

If SIM card is not presented, pls first check the GET_SIM_STATUS in your log, if the state is absent, you should check the modem part.